# How can I add a condition to this while loop?

Tags: c++, while-loop

I'm relatively knew to programming in c++ and in general. I am struggling to add a condition to my while loop that is already performing some data validation.

```
    int again;
cout << "Do you want to search again?\n[1] Yes\n[2] No\n\n Please choose your option:  ";
cin >> again;
while (!(cin >> again)) {
  cout << "Please enter a valid number: ";
  cin.clear(); //clears the input
  cin.ignore(1000, '\n');// clears 1000 characters of input
}
```

While the validation is working, as I said above I am struggling to get a condition in there that requires the user to enter 1 or 2 as the options state all in one while loop.

Thank you.

Comment: Look up "logical operators" in the context of C++.

Comment: `while (!(cin >> again) || (again != 1 && again != 2))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some may find more readable a loop with conditions inside the body.

```
int again = 0;
for(;;)
{ 
    std::cout << "Do you want to search again?\n"
                 "[1] Yes\n"
                 "[2] No\n\n"
                 "Please choose your option:  ";
    std::cin >> again;
    if ( std::cin.eof() )
    {
         std::cerr << "Unexpected end of input.\n";
         again = 2;  // No, you probably don't want to search again.
         break;
    }
    if ( !std::cin )
    {
         std::cout << "Please enter a valid number.\n";
         std::cin.clear();
         std::cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
         continue;
    }
    if ( again == 1  ||  again == 2)
    {
         break;
    }
    std::cout << "Please enter 1 or 2.\n";
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much for your help. Thank you all.